# Will any modern browsers *not* move DIV elements from the HEAD to the BODY?

Tags: html, wordpress

I am looking for an easy way to insert content at the top of the `<body>` section in a WordPress plugin, and discovered that there is no core hook to do this, and I can't rely on modifying the theme. However there is a hook to insert in to the `<head>` section, and I discovered that if I insert the `<div>` into the `<head>` section rather than the `<body>`, all browsers I've tested will in fact move that content from the `<head>` to the top of the `<body>` section which is just what I want.

I know this fails W3C validation which is bad, on the other hand most sites have W3C validation errors. And more importantly, this trick works on Chrome, FF, IE, Safari, Android, and iPhone, Chrome mobile, Brave mobile, Ghostery mobile, to name a few places I've checked.

Will this kind of code cause problems in practice? Should I avoid doing this and find another way?

Run this HTML code and you'll see both DIVs in the body after the page renders:

```
<html>
<head>
<div>This is the head</div>
</head>
<body>
    <div>This is the body</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's what you'll see in your browser:
[image]

Comment: There are no known browsers from the last 20 years that will not do this in HTML mode. Even Internet Explorer 5 does this.

Comment: Wow, that seems pretty stunning to me but my own testing supports your comment. Given that this is a defacto standard, maybe it's time to change the HTML specs so we can rely on this without having to ask. In the mean time, at least some people might find this question and your comment useful.

Comment: This behavior is in fact covered in the spec, just not the part that says elements that belong in the body should be allowed in the head, because allowing that would be a violation of common sense. It's covered in the part that describes how invalid markup should be, and is, handled interoperably, and only for the sake of backwards compatibility. The stock "just because you can doesn't mean you should" disclaimer applies.

Comment: The div isn't moved from the end, it just implies the end of the head and the start of the body. The end tag for the head and the start tag for the body are then ignored. (Well, almost. I think there might be some rules about retroactively applying attributes on the body start tag to the existing body element)

Comment: Thank you Quentin - that's pretty significant and I just confirmed this with my own experiment. What this means is that all elements in the head following the div tag will also get moved to the top of the head *even if they are valid*. So now I am wondering this: Does moving all these other elements from the head to the top of the body in this way change the way the pay renders or behaves? Maybe that's the bigger issue?

Answer (score 1):

## Updated Answer

So you have some pretty strict requirements:

- No theme editing (initiated via plugin)
- No JavaScript insert (needs to be in initial DOM)

If you just need to have the element high on the page, you could stick it on a relatively early hook, and then move it after `<body>` with JavaScript.

If it needs to be one of the first things loaded, you probably *could* just stick it in the `wp_head` - making sure it's just got a really low priority so it makes quasi-semantic sense.

However you could also insert it with PHP using a real-time find and replace. You shouldn't suffer too much of a performance hit, but something like this would get you started:

```
function Danger_insert_iframe( $buffer ){
    // Define your iframe
    $iframe = '<iframe src="https://xhynk.com" style="width: 100%; height: 150px;"></iframe>';

    // Match the first `<body>` tag
    preg_match( '/(?:<body.*>)/U', $buffer, $matches );

    // Return our buffer with iframe appended to the body match
    return str_replace( $matches[0], $matches[0].$iframe, $buffer );
}

// An early hook with the DOM ready to fire on
add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){
    ob_start();
    ob_start( 'Danger_insert_iframe' );
});
```

What this does is matches the

```
<body [any class/js/data attributes here]>
```

and will then replace it with

```
<body [any class/js/data attributes here]><iframe></iframe>
```

Here's a <kbd>[Working Demo](https://xhynk.com/headless/danger-example/)</kbd>

It's not exactly elegant, but it will get the job done. The first thing that came to mind was a regex match for the body, but you may be better with another manipulation method like `DOMDocument`. For now though, this will get you started.

---

## Original Answer:

> ```html
> While there's not really a *perfect* way to go about this, I would avoid _hacking_ a solution together. I've seen all sorts of strange things, including hooking in a `</head>` to `wp_head`, and directly inserting content like you've mentioned.
>
> Your best best, and the most "accepted" way to do this, is to use a [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). Ultimately, it will use the parent theme like the regular theme, but you can override parts of it with the child theme. This is *mostly* future-proof, unless the parent theme structure *radically* changes.
>
> This gist of these would be to set up a blank Child Theme, and copy the `header.php` (or equivalent file) from the parent theme, and find the opening body tag, usually `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`
>
> Then, insert your own [`do_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/), so the new file will start with:
>
>     <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
>     <?php do_action('Danger_after_body'); ?>
>
> Then create a `functions.php` file in the Child Theme and use that to deal with content on that hook.
>
>     add_action( 'Danger_after_body', 'Danger_insert_content' );
>     function Danger_insert_content(){
>         echo 'This Content is always after the &lt;body&gt; tag';
>     }
>
> If this won't work for you (truthfully, it should except in a few instances), and you are just inserting simple content - you could just target the `body` with JavaScript and insert content that way.
>
> You could also find the first hook that fires in your current theme and add high priority functions to that, but depending on the theme layout that can get messy and falls under the strange hack solutions I mentioned earlier.
> ```

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Since I'm distributing a plugin, I believe it's not possible for me to set up a child theme or modify or hook in to the current theme. Unless there's a way to do this from a plugin? Fortunately, I am in fact inserting very simple content.

Comment: Unfortunately that does complicate it a bit. What kind of content are you inserting, can you provide an html and screenshot example?

Comment: In truth I am inserting one element - an <iframe src='...'></iframe>; I am not really inserting a div but a div was easier to explain the question. Are there any work-arounds for inserting at the top of the head if you can't create a child theme? Writing JavaScript to dynamically create the element does not work for various reasons - it has to be in the initial DOM structure.

Comment: I've updated the answer - you may be best off matching the `<body>` tag and inserting your iframe with a "real time find and replace" of sorts.